# How to create a mirror of a private maven repository?

Tags: maven, mirroring

We have Sonatype nexus repository where we publish artifacts. I want to mirror that repository in a different server located in a different office location. Is there a opensource tool to mirror an entire repository? Note: I am not talking about proxy repositories or caches. I want active mirroring with the two repositories more or less in sync.

Comment: Use another Nexus repository manager and configure to use the original one as input...really mirroring is only possible via commercial tools (Nexus Cluster)...

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup one as a main repository  (basically the one you have) and then the second one in proxy configuration, see this detailed instruction:
https://help.sonatype.com/learning/repository-manager-3/first-time-installation-and-setup/lesson-2%3A-proxy-and-hosted-maven-repositories#app